# 256 colors on tmux not working properly

Tags: vim, tmux, colors

I have this vim theme:

[image: vim material]

and enabling 256 colors on tmux, looks different:

[image]

Keywords highlighting is working fine but the background color changes...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `export TERM=screen-256color` before starting `vim`?

Comment: Yes I have and it's actually worst. It removes the syntax highlighting